# deleting rectangles (eating apples)

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

im trying to make a game where the player eats an apple and has to delete a rectangle after the player has collided with it but im getting an errer of: AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'remove'

```
import pygame
import sys




player_pos=x,y,width,height=(0,0,50,50)
enemy_pos=e_x,e_y,e_width,e_height=(200,0,50,50)

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,440))
FPS=pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                y-=25

            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                y+=25

            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x+=25

            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                x-=25


            if player1.colliderect(enemy1):
                enemy1.remove()

screen.fill((0,0,0))
player1=pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(x,y,width,height))
enemy1=pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,255),(e_x,e_y,e_width,e_height))
pygame.display.update()
FPS.tick(120)
```

Comment: What is your question? What from the error don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "remove" an object form the scene, all you have to do is stop drawing it.
Add a variable `draw_enemy` and initialize it to `True`. When the player collides with the enemy set the variable to `False`. Draw the enemy depending on the state of `draw_enemy`:

```py
draw_enemy = True

while True:
    # [...]

    if player1.colliderect(enemy1):
        draw_enemy = False

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    player1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(x,y,width,height))

    if draw_enemy:
        enemy1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,255),(e_x,e_y,e_width,e_height))

    pygame.display.update()
```

---

Alternatively create the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before ahead:

```py
player_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(200, 0, 50, 50)
```

Create a new random position of the object when the collision is detected:

```py
if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
    enemy_rect.x = random.randrange(0, 975, 25)
    enemy_rect.y = random.randrange(0, 425, 25)
```

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,440))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(200, 0, 50, 50)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                player_rect.y -= 25
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_rect.y += 25
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_rect.x += 25
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_rect.x -= 25
    
    if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
        enemy_rect.x = random.randrange(0, 975, 25)
        enemy_rect.y = random.randrange(0, 425, 25)

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), player_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), enemy_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: but what about the respawn

Comment: @Dartanansams Which respawn? You didn't talk about that before. Do you want to spawn the apple on an other random position?

Comment: @D See the 2nd part of the answer.